# Quering date and time field and render in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

views.py

```
def new_report(request):
    user = request.user
    reports = Report.objects.filter(user=user)
    today = datetime.datetime.today()

    reports_today = reports.filter(created_date_time__year=today.year, created_date_time__month=today.month, created_date_time__day=today.day)
    num_today = len(reports_today) + 1
    num_today = str(num_today).zfill(3)
    reportform = ReportForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        reportform = ReportForm(request.POST)
        if reportform.is_valid():
            report = reportform.save(commit=False)
            report.user = user
            report.created_date_time = today
    return render(request, 'incident/new_report.html',
                  {
                   'newreport_menu': True,
                   'reports': reports,
                   'reportform':ReportForm,
                 })
```

models.py

```
class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    incident_number = models.CharField('Incident Number', max_length=100)
    device_id = models.CharField('Device Id', max_length=100)
    app_uuid = models.CharField('Unique App Id', max_length=100)
    created_date_time = models.DateTimeField('Created',auto_now=True)
```

template is

```
{{ reports.created_date_time|date:"j M Y g:i A" }}
```

Fetching the created_date_time from database and convert to this format `20 Jan2011 at 2:26PM` to display in template.

To query the created_date_time from database and display into template.I am not getting any error in the code,i think some logic having problem so that it is not happening.

Comment: Looks like `reports` variable is a list of Report objects, but you access to it in template as it is a single Report object. Try this: `{{ reports.0.created_date_time|date:"j M Y g:i A" }}`

Comment: ya,it is displaying the date and time,but in this format 4 May 2013 10:00 PM ,so i need it to be in this 4 May 2013 at 10:00 PM format i.e between date and time a string "at" should include,how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reports` variable is accessed in template as it is a single Report object, but it is a list of Report object.

To access to the first item in list in template, use following syntax:

```
{{ reports.0.created_date_time|date:"j M Y g:i A" }}
```

Now, the easiest way to print date in format you've mentioned is:

```
{{ reports.0.created_date_time|date:"j M Y" }} at {{ reports.0.created_date_time|date:"g:i A" }}
```

But, to my mind, the better way is to create [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/), that will print the desired format.

your_app/templatetags/format_dates.py

```
from django.utils.dateformat import format
from django.template.base import Library

register = Library()

@register.filter(expects_localtime=True, is_safe=False)
def format_date(value):
    if not value:
        return u''
    try:
        return u"%s at %s" % (format(value, 'j M Y'), format(value, 'g:i A'))
    except AttributeError:
        return u''
```

and then in template:

```
{% load format_dates %}

...

{{ reports.0.created_date_time|format_date }}
```